Unable to load MNIST data set due to SSL error in keras...load_data() function
import keras
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
...

I currently started with machine learning, but I'm unable to load the MNIST data set due to an error thats says:

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

I ensured that everything was up to date (macOS version 14.5, pip version 24.1, latest tensorflow and keras libraries and up-to-date safari and vscode versions). I have tried reinstalling keras several times, made sure to not download it from pip3 cache with the latest pip 24.1 version. This error keeps persisting and I haven't found a fix yet. The only part I've figured out is that it is an error resulting from the ...load_data() function.
How to resolve this issue?

Never mind, I found an extremely simple fix: Just run the Install Certificates.command that comes bundled in the folder when you install python3 from the web.

if you are working on MacOS, add below code blcok on top of your porgram. It will sove the issue
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
